# Is it possible to edit/update a Facebook link post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm wondering is it possible to edit/update a Facebook link post, which is already posted on the page.

It's a link post which is getting info from website meta tags, so I'm wondering if there's a way maybe through Open Graph to edit the meta tags, and the post would update itself?

Thanks